# Random sound onClick Android Medaplayer

Tags: android, audio, onclick

I have got this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ingame_voice_42_);

Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1); 

bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mpButtonClick.start();

    }
});

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

How to change it, for play random sound from /raw/ folder.
Is a simple method to change this code for this?

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the sounds in a seperate file in assets (/assets/mysounds/).
2. Get the list of the sounds:

   ```
   AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
   String[] sounds= assetManager.list("mysounds");
   ```
3. Set your MediaPlayer to a random sound:

   ```
   final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, "mysounds/"+sounds[some_random_int]);
   ```

Comment: What i must replace with: mContext?
I've got an error:
mContext cannot be resolved

change to 'this'?

OK but now i've got:
Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: I can't give You a log, 'cause i can't run it.

What must I change in:

[code]        final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, "mysounds/"+sounds[some_random_int]);
[/code]
Exctacly here:
+sounds[some_random_int]);

because i've got these errors:
sounds cannot be resolved to a variable

and

some_random_int cannot be resolved to a variable


Sorry, I'm newbie.

Comment: Then how did you get an IOException?!! You SHOULD replace `some_random_int` with random int. I put it as a place holder.

Comment: for example:
  final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create this, "mysounds/"+sounds[sound1, sound2]);  ??

I've got this error in create :
The method create(Context, Uri) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, String)